# using MSAL Authentication in WASM Application calls to Microsoft Graph and custom API

Tags: azure-active-directory, webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I implement this to login the user using WASM standalone app.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);}
```

It works great. When I try to add the scope for the graph and my api. It does not allow the login.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
   options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");               
   options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://xsc.com/xxEmployees.Read.All");
)
```

The error says AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource.  How do I get this to work?
I looked at AcquireTokenSilent it uses a Microsoft.Identity.Client is this my only option. If it is my next question is how to I take my authenticated user AuthenticationStateprovider and create a IAccount for the AcquireTokenSilent method. Any ideas or other ways to try this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Msal is based on azure ad so that along the policy of azure ad, you can't generate an access token for two or more types of scopes at the same time.

[This page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1390) also mentioned it, the only way seems to generate token seperately and call api for 2 times.